# Substracting from an indexed value

Tags: vba, excel

This is the first question I am posting here...
I am stuck with substracting an indexed value. I have given the code below...

```
Sub index()
Dim var As Variant
Dim var1 As Variant

var = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(Worksheets("Stocks").Range("D:E"),  _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Invoice").Range("B12").Value,  _
    Worksheets("Stocks").Range("B:B"), 0), 2)
var1 = Worksheets("Invoice").Range("C12").Value

var.Value = var - var1
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors? I can tell you from a quick scan that you don't want the `.Value` in `var.Value`.

Answer (score 1):

Try it as,

```
Sub index()

    dim rw as variant
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim var1 As Variant

    rw = Application.Match(Worksheets("Invoice").Range("B12").Value, Worksheets("Stocks").Range("B:B"), 0)
    if not iserror(rw) then
        var = Worksheets("Stocks").cells(rw, "E").value2
        var1 = Worksheets("Invoice").Range("C12").Value2
        var = var - var1
        debug.print var
    else
        debug.print "no match for " & Worksheets("Invoice").Range("B12").Value
    end if
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped.. thanks a lot for the prompt response...however it isnt working but then...while researching I was able to figure out another way by using "Set" function before var and it worked... :)
And below...let me give the code which worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
Sub index()
Dim var As Variant
Dim var1 As Variant

Set var = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(Worksheets("Stocks").Range("D:E"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Invoice").Range("B12").Value, Worksheets("Stocks").Range("B:B"), 0), 2)
var1 = Worksheets("Invoice").Range("C12").Value

var.Value = var - var1
End Sub
```